# THREE.WebGLShader: Shader Couldn't Compile; 's_noise_1_2' : no matching overloaded function found

Tags: fragment-shader, vertex-shader, glslify

I've been toying with some THREE.js examples and have been trying to compile a few shaders that were inclued in an example, specifically: https://github.com/brunoimbrizi/interactive-particles

If you navigate to src/shaders/ you'll find the shaders I am trying to compile. I'm currently running a React app and have been updating this code to meet my personal project needs, but I've run into these issues along the way:

[No matching overloaded function found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxvat.png)

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer 98

THREE.WebGLShader: Shader couldn't compile.
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex WARNING: 0:1: 'glslify' : unrecognized pragma
ERROR: 0:40: 'snoise_1_2' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:49: 'snoise_1_2' : no matching overloaded function found
```

I've tried refactoring the vertex/fragment shader code in multiple different ways, but with the same outcome regardless of my attempted solution. Seems like the support for something like this in React is pretty minimal, although gl-react seemed almost helpful, but I don't need shaders in component form.

*particleFrag.js*

```js
const glsl = require('glslify');

export const fragShader = glsl`precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;

varying vec2 vPUv;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0);
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    vec2 puv = vPUv;

    vec4 colA = texture2D(uTexture, puv);

    float grey = colA.r * 0.21 + colA.g * 0.71 + colA.b * 0.07;
    vec4 colB = vec4(grey, grey, grey, 1.0);

    float border = 0.3;
    float radius = 0.5;
    float dist = radius - distance(uv, vec2(0.5));
    float t = smoothstep(0.0, border, dist);

    color = colB;
    color.a = t;

    gl_FragColor = color;
}`;
```

*particleVert.js*

```js
const glsl = require('glslify');


export const vertShader = glsl`#pragma glslify: snoise2 = require(glsl-noise/simplex/2d)

precision highp float;

attribute float pindex;
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 offset;
attribute vec2 uv;
attribute float angle;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

uniform float uTime;
uniform float uRandom;
uniform float uDepth;
uniform float uSize;
uniform vec2 uTextureSize;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform sampler2D uTouch;

varying vec2 vPUv;
varying vec2 vUv;

float random(float n) {
    return fract(sin(n) * 43758.5453123);
}

void main() {
    vUv = uv;

    vec2 puv = offset.xy / uTextureSize;
    vPUv = puv;

    vec4 colA = texture2D(uTexture, puv);
    float grey = colA.r * 0.21 + colA.g * 0.71 + colA.b * 0.07;

    vec3 displaced = offset;
    displaced.xy += vec2(random(pindex) - 0.5, random(offset.x + pindex) - 0.5) * uRandom;
    float rndz = (random(pindex) + snoise_1_2(vec2(pindex * 0.1, uTime * 0.1)));
    displaced.z += rndz * (random(pindex) * 2.0 * uDepth);
    displaced.xy -= uTextureSize * 0.5;

    float t = texture2D(uTouch, puv).r;
    displaced.z += t * 20.0 * rndz;
    displaced.x += cos(angle) * t * 20.0 * rndz;
    displaced.y += sin(angle) * t * 20.0 * rndz;

    float psize = (snoise_1_2(vec2(uTime, pindex) * 0.5) + 2.0);
    psize *= max(grey, 0.2);
    psize *= uSize;

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(displaced, 1.0);
    mvPosition.xyz += position * psize;
    vec4 finalPosition = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    gl_Position = finalPosition;
}`;
```

Defining the material:

```js
const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
            uniforms,
            vertexShader: shaders.particle.vert,
            fragmentShader: shaders.particle.frag,
            depthTest: false,
            transparent: true,
            // blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
        });
```

And everything stems from this render call:

```js
draw() {
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
```

I'm obviously need of the shaders compiling, my inexperience with this sort of thing is making it difficult to implement in a React project.

Comment: Hi! Welceome to SO. Adding the acutal console output as text in your question is more helpful than a link to a screenshot. If you must use a screenshot, embedding the image using image markup is more helpful than a link.  Thanks!

Comment: @GeneZ.Ragan Noted. I will make sure to do that quickly!

Comment: glslify [is a build time system](https://github.com/glslify/glslify). You set it up with other tools and it takes your source code and generates new code. You run the new code.  And of course you `snoise_1_2` is undefined as your code doesn't define it. There is no built in function called `snoise_1_2`. Google for it or look through the the code of the example your copying.

Comment: @gman I tried renaming snoise_1_2 to snoise2 to no avail. For some reason it would throw the same error as the latter. I went through documentation for glsl-noise and followed the gettinfg started exactly, but no luck. I had already done this prior to this post.

Comment: there is no snoise2 funciton either. snoise?? is a user fucntion written by a user. It is not part of webgl. glslify is a program that runs at build time to replace the `#pragma glslify ...` with the contents of other files **at build time**. **At build time** means it's a program you run from the command line that processes your source code and outputs it somewhere else on your drive. You run the result of that processing in your browser not the original code. [Read the instructions on glslify](https://github.com/glslify/glslify) and then use one of the methods, webpack, babel, or browserify.

Comment: @gman Okay, I will have to definitely try out what you have said there. From the glsl-noise library (https://github.com/hughsk/glsl-noise), I followed the documentation as can be seen in the README. What I have written there _should_ be working.

They have the following:

```#pragma glslify: snoise2 = require(glsl-noise/simplex/2d)```

Comment: That documetation is terse. It assumes you know that glslify is a build time tool that would take the example shown in the README and transform it into something that can actually run in the browser. It does not run as is. It has to run through a tool (browserify/babel/rollup/webpack/...) that has been configured to use the glslify plugin to transform that example into working code. The glslify readme has details on that.

Comment: @gman I think this (https://gist.github.com/Bjvanminnen/595d9fef3b1320d1f94632f8c2d323ef) would be something I would need to setup in that case. I had already tried running with webpack, but I was having issues with that and its configuration in correspondence to this being a react-app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing the following:

- Added support for Babel/Webpack for my project.
- Rendered the particilized image in a "container" defined by a CSS class.
- Verified support for glslify in webpack.

There were lots of changes made to get this operational in a React project, but transpiling with Babel and Webpack seemed to do the trick since there was webpack support for the shader files.

If you have any questions about how more specifically I got this operational feel free to shoot me a message!

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
                use: [
                    require.resolve('raw-loader'),
                    require.resolve('glslify-loader'),
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.module\.s([ac])ss$/,
                loader: [
                    isDevelopment ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            sourceMap: isDevelopment
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: isDevelopment
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s([ac])ss$/,
                exclude: /\.module.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
                loader: [
                    isDevelopment ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: isDevelopment
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 10000
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.css', '.html', '.json', '.png']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: isDevelopment ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Hi! I am trying to implement the same tutorial in my React app and I am hitting the same errors, the pragma one and the _1_2 one. Can you, please, tell me what did you modify in order to work with React? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Config

webpack.config

```
{
      test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs|vert|frag)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ['raw-loader', 'glslify-loader'],
}
```

### 2. edit vertex shader

In particle.vert replace `snoise_1_2` with `snoise2`

### 3. install required packages

`npm i glsl-noise`